# Dismiss Game Center in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-center

This is what I have in MyScene.m

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKLabelNode *touchedNode = (SKLabelNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];
if ([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:@"Leaderboard"])
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController    alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
        leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        if (gameCenterController != nil)
        {
            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }

    }
}
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*)gameCenterViewController 
{
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I've set a sprite as the leaderboard button, It opens the leaderboard but I can't close it.
The code gives me no error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController{
    [gameCenterViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
}`